# Passing file contents to a c executable doesn't seem to work

Tags: c, unix, zsh

I have this **c executable** called `testFile` file containing this code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    printf("Number of arguments : %d\n Arguments : ", argc);
    for(int i = 0; i<argc-1;i++){
        printf("%s\t", argv[i]);
    }
}
```

and along with it a file called `test1` containing just the number 1 (`echo 1 > test1`)

When I call this line on the command line (`zsh`) : 
`./test < test1`

 the output I get is this :

```
Number of arguments : 1
Arguments : ./testFile
```

Shouldn't this show 2 arguments ? Along with the character 1 ? I want to find a way to make this 1 appear in the arguments list, is it possible ? Or is it just the way my shell handles arguments passed like that ? (I find it weird as `cat < test1` prints `1`)

Comment: `./test < test1` calls `./test` with no arguments.  The shell parses that line and calls `./test` with no arguments after redirecting its stdin from `test`.

Comment: `cat < test1` is not weird. `cat` reads _stdin_. For this command, the shell has set up _stdin_ as coming from the file `test1`. Simple! You should know that `cat` can take multiple arguments (eg: `cat file1 file2 > file3`) Try `cat test1 - test1`... The isolated hyphen will cause `cat` to pause, waiting for keyboard (stdin) input until Ctrl-D, then continue with the next file in the list. Bright people wrote very bright programs long ago.

Comment: It might be interesting to note the output of things like `cat < test1 test2 - test3` or `<test1 cat test2 -` or `cat test1 < test2 test3 -`

Comment: *along with it a file called `test1` containing just the number 1 (`echo 1 > test1`)*  That file contains the number 1 and a newline character.  `echo` by default terminates its output with a newline.  In some contexts, that might matter significantly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're conflating standard input with command arguments.

`main`'s `argc` and `argv` are used for passing command line arguments.

here, for example,  the shell invokes `echo` with 1 command line argument (the `1` character), and with its standard output attached to a newly opened and truncated file `test`.

```
echo 1 > test1
```

here, the shell running `test` with 0 arguments and its standard input attached to a newly opened `test1` file.

```
./test < test1
```

If you want to turn the contents of `./test1` into command line parameters for `test`, you can do it with `xargs`.

```
xargs test < test1
```

unrelated to your question:

```
    for(int i = 0; i<argc+1;i++){
```

The condition for that should be `i<argc`.  Like all arrays in C and just about every other language, the minimum valid index of `argv` is  0 and the maximum valid index is 1 less than its length.  As commenters pointed out, `argv[argc]` is required to be NULL, so technically, `argc` is one less than the length of `argv`.

Comment: Thanks, just to make it very clear for others `scanf()` will catch the input when passed this way.

Comment: Small correction in this special case: `maximum valid index is argc-1`... Apparently it is now "standard" that `argv[]` is analogous to a C string. Apparently, some standard, somewhere, **requires** that `argv[ argc ]` be set to a NULL pointer... (Just like `strlen( "cat" );` can count on the '\0' terminator.) Just fyi...

Comment: C11 5.1.2.2.1 states "argv[argc] shall be a null pointer." Been that way as long as I can remember.

Comment: @Fe2O3: It's been like that since there was a standard. If you have a copy of K&R 2nd edition (1988), you'll find on page 115 "additionally, the standard requires that `argv[argc]` be a null pointer." (That phrase was added between the first and second editions; the second edition reflects what was then the newly-agreed standard.) But that doesn't make it possible to pass `argv[argc]` to a `%s` format conversion in `printf()`.

Comment: @rici Thanks for the reference. I learned C from the first edition 10 years before "K&R: the sequel." `:-)` Just wanted to clarify that comment "the maximum valid index" is not precisely correct. Code doesn't really need 'argc' if it only wants to process `argv[ x ]` until `argv [ x ] == NULL`... 'K' was a great clarifier and 'R' was a genius, imho... Glad they didn't ask for commission from my wages `:-)`

Comment: @FE2O3: Me too. That's why I have both of them on my bookshelf. (Also the fact that I hate throwing books away.)

Comment: good point folks, I'll correct the answer to refer to array length

Answer (score 2):

If you want the contents of `test1` to be available in `argv`, you can do:

```
./test $(cat test1)
```

Note that this is very different than:

```
./test "$(cat test1)"
```

which is also different from:

```
./test '$(cat test1)'.  # Does not do at all what you want!
```

The first option will present each "word" of the file as a distinct argument, while the second will present the contents of the file as a single argument.  The single quotes version doesn't look inside the file at all, and is merely included here to give you something to experiment with.

Comment: I'd add that all of these options will fail for a file with binary data - command-line arguments are passed as *strings* - `char` arrays terminated with a `'\0'` value.  There'd be no way to determine what binary data was actually passed.  (Well, no *easy* way that's conformant with the C standard and not dependent on the internal details of whatever platform you're running on...)

Comment: `$(cat fiename)` is tricky to work with which is why I generally prefer `xargs`

Answer (score 0):

`argv[0]` is always the name of the executable itself. With your way of invoking the command, you did not pass any command at all. You would have to invoke it from zsh as `./testFile test1` if you want your program to see the **name** of the data file, or  `./testFile $(<test1)` if you want it to see the **content** of the data file.